# Date Format MM/dd/yyyy Returning single Digit Months/Days

Tags: jasper-reports

I have strings, startDate, endDate, showStartDate, and showEndDate. Any text field I use them in will dislay 01/01/2020 12:00AM as 1/1/2020 12:00AM. I just want 01/01/2020. Nothing I have done, including use of 'Pattern' in the field settings, has changed the format. What else can I try?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Your field has to be of `java.util.Date` type to make 'pattern' to work, not String.

Comment: I'm learning as I go. How do I make the change within Jaspersoft Studio? I've seen some posts talking about reformatting the data received from a query. How do I know what is coming back?